# Bootstrap grid system with angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I am trying grid system using bootstrap css but not coming properly. I followed  [getbootstrap CSS](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/)

CSS:

```
@import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

[Scrip here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-grid-plpmd5?file=app%2Fnested.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all your `nested-app` inside a `col-md-9` inside `row` and based on the `nested-app` code that have no sense.

you can fix that by doing something like this:
in your **app.component.ts**:

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 border">.col-md-3</div>
        <div class="col-md-9 border">.col-md.9</div>
    </div>
    <nested-app>
    </nested-app>
</div>
```

Comment: actually the grid system is working. What do you want exactly ?

Comment: Can you edit my stackblitz? Becuase here it is not working.

Comment: @AppleOrange What's not working about it? You need to be more specific and let us know exactly what error you're seeing, and what the behaviour *should* be

Comment: I am geting only text..not getting proper alignment

Comment: Are you sure it's not just because the iframe is set to smaller than `md`? What happens if you open https://angular-bootstrap-grid-plpmd5.stackblitz.io/ and set it to maximised?

Comment: It's your code, just opened in a full window: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-grid-plpmd5?file=app%2Fnested.component.html

Comment: Thanks..Working Now